# Loop through files and save them separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I want to loop trough a local folder with a couple thousand text files, remove the stop-words, and save the files in a sub-folder. My code loops through all files, but writes all text files in ONE new file. I need the files separated - as they where, and with the **exact same filename**, just without the stop-words. What am I doing wrong?

```
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import glob
import os
import codecs

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    file1 = codecs.open(afile, encoding='utf-8')
    line = file1.read()
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_without_stop_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    new_words = " ".join(words_without_stop_words).strip()
    appendFile = open('subfolder/file1.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
    appendFile.write(new_words)
    appendFile.close()
```

I see that the filename(s) will be "file1" (line 11) - I just can't get my head around glob (if glob is even the solution?).

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to have separate files, then why use the same filename in the 2nd ``open``, instead of building new filenames using ``afile``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Solution:**

```
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import glob
import os
import codecs

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    file1 = codecs.open(afile, encoding='utf-8')
    line = file1.read()
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_without_stop_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    new_words = " ".join(words_without_stop_words).strip()

    subfolder = getSubfolder(afile)
    filename = getFilename(afile)
    appendFile = open('{}/{}.txt'.format(subfolder,filename),'w', encoding='utf-8')
    appendFile.write(new_words)
    appendFile.close()
```

I've never worked with glob or codecs, i believe your problem lies in your last 3 lines of code. You use a constant string ('subfolder/file1.txt') as a final file target - that's why your results land in one file. I replaced the target path with two variables. These variables i get from the functions "getSubfolder()" and "getFilename()". You have to implement these functions in order to get the filename you need.

If i understand your goal correct, your filename stays the same, just in a different folder. Then you can use this line:

```
    appendFile = open('{}/{}.txt'.format('mysubfolder',afile),'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Solution while learning:**

[image]

I would recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/inducer/pudb and follow the execution of every step of your loop. This way you will see and learn what python does, what variable has what value at a certain point in time, and so on.

Comment: This worked just fine with your appendFile line! And I will take a closer look at pudb, did not know that such an amazing tool existed.

Comment: You're welcome. This tool looks pretty nerdy but is really awesome for small scripts-debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are using same name in loop. You should change the name of file in each iteration. for example you can try this:

```
counter = 0 # This line added
for afile in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    file1 = codecs.open(afile, encoding='utf-8')
    line = file1.read()
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_without_stop_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    new_words = " ".join(words_without_stop_words).strip()
    appendFile = open('subfolder/file1' + str(counter) + ".txt",'w', encoding='utf-8') # This line changed
    appendFile.write(new_words)
    appendFile.close()
    counter += 1 # This line added
```

What here happened is: we added a counter variable and add that number at the end of the name of each file.

At the end of the loop we increase the `counter` for separating files.

you can try different things like adding original file name at the end of the new file  name.

Comment: That works. But is it possible to keep the original filename?

Comment: You mean the `afile`  name or `file1.txt`?